# nginx as a proxy for apache and jenkins

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 and I would use Nginx (at localhost:80) as a proxy (reverse ?) for Apache2 (at localhost:8080) and Jenkins (at localhost:8000).

The question is: why **all** the images are not loaded?

My configurations are:

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/apache2
    DirectoryIndex index.html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/apache2.localhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/apache2.localhost/www
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    ServerName apache2.localhost

    ErrorLog /var/www/html/apache2.localhost/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/apache2.localhost/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html/nginx;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /apache2/ {
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://apache2.localhost:8080/;
    }

    location /jenkins/ {
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error in your browsers debug console? What  is the URL that your browser gets from the server for a failed image? where does the error come from, nginx, apache or jenkins? What do the error logs of the servers say?

Comment: For each image I get a 404.
EDIT:
From the inspect I see that the image URL is like "http://localhost/icons/ubuntu-logo.png" from the page localhost/apache2/ that has a index the apache default page.

Answer (score 0):

I have partially solved the problem with that guide about jenkins:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy

This is my config file (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    location /jenkins/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/jenkins/;
        sendfile off;

        proxy_set_header   Host             $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

        # This is the maximum upload size
        client_max_body_size       10m;
        client_body_buffer_size    128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout      90;
        proxy_send_timeout         90;
        proxy_read_timeout         90;

        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

        # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_request_buffering off;
        proxy_buffering off; # Required for HTTP-based CLI to work over SSL
    }

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name _;
}
```

I will post the complete solution asap